# HTML page layout - multiple form tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I have a twitter-bootstrap & thymeleaf project where I need to have two form tags covering the respective parts of the page as shown below:

[image: page layout]

The area represented by the **black box** contains two text areas and a submit button. Users can type text into textbox1 and hit submit. the text they type is displayed in textbox2 as date+time+user+commentstring. At the same time it is save in the data base. textbox2 is to hold multiple comments each prefixed with date time and user.

The area represented by the **red box** is the remainder of the form - it has several fields that will be sent to the backend when the main submit button is clicked.

I understand  tags must be closed within the element that they are opened in. Given this constraint - can I have a form tag that covers the red area using bootstrap grid layout. Non-layout centered solutions are welcome.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate better :

`Layout example` https://jsfiddle.net/0an6vwdq/8/

The two large text boxes and *submit note* button are area 1. The rest is area 2.

**UPDATE 2**

The fiddle has the second set of form tags starting on line 24 and closing on line 54 - right after due date picker - the form tags close early and miss the dynamic list at the bottom of the page.

I had to close them early because of the bootstrap grid system and the opening tag being inside a row.

So the question is still how to maintain this layout with bootstrap grid system but have second form tags cover remainder of page.

Comment: Float the first form to the left.

Comment: That is a weird layout. Cant you use one form and style how you need the elements? Then use JS to determine what to send when submitting? Or as @MrLister said....

Comment: @Gezzasa That is not nearly as straightforward as simply having two forms. Think of the code maintainer, later on! K.I.S.S.!

Comment: Do you want the second form to start beside the first form or on the new row in the block under the first form?

Comment: @Deathstorm I would like the top of the second form to start to the right of the first form with the tops even.

Comment: @AlGrant You are asking about specific aspects of layout that involve HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap, so I think it's only fair that you provide us a [mcve] that has HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `float: left;` on the first form element.

```css
.small {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
}

.big {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<form class="small">

</form>

<form class="big">

</form>
```

Comment: are you able to demonstrate that answer using bootstrap grid layout?

Comment: Just add this piece of CSS to it or share your code with us.

Comment: Use a fiddle service or post here? Whats usual?

Comment: I would create a fiddle and edit the post and add the link to it.

Comment: But if you look at my fiddle I have to close the second form tag before the bottom of the page because it it opened inside a row div.

Comment: The solution I implemented had nothing to do with the layout in the end - but in terms of the way I asked this question - this is the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in bootstrap, however you may try this.

```
<form id="plan" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#" th:Action="@{/plan}" th:object="${file}">
<div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: lightgray">
</div></form>
```

Instead of this.

```
<div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: lightgray">
<form id="plan" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#" th:Action="@{/plan}" th:object="${file}">
</form</div>
```